# relative include comparison

Tags: php, include

i have been searching now for a few days on the internet for how to include files from the websites root. now i found a solution by making a Global config file that sits on the root of my website and including it in every file that needs it.

```
<?php define('SITE_ROOT', dirname(__FILE__));
```

that solved the problem for most of my includes But it fails when in need to include config.php inside a running included file. now i have written a simple php script dealing with that.

```
$i = 0;
$path = '';
$file = "config.php";
while($i != true){
 if(file_exists($path . $file)){
    include_once($path . $file);
    $i = true;
 }else{
    $path .= '../';
 }
}
```

i put that instead for searching the file on my website. now my question is there a better solution for this or is this bad practise.

while commenting please keep in mind i am still a beginner programmer

thanks

Comment: Have you tried this `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` to get the root?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look up `explode()` and `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`. With the latter you will get the path from the root to the script you are 'executing'. With explode() you could cut the path in units, which will give you the depth (plus 1) of where your actual script is located. So, if you want to create the relative path, with `str_repeat("../", ...)`, you're there!

Example: `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` returns:

```
/misc/tests/test.php
```

then

```
$depth = explode("/", dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']));
```

will give you a list of elements. The path to root is:

```
$toroot = str_repeat("../", count($depth) - 1);
```